# Google Closure Compiler, some properties will never be renamed?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

today I've found an issue related with property rename by the Google Closure Compiler. Would be happy if somebody could explain me why this code:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

// ADD YOUR CODE HERE


console.info({
  foo: 'bar',
  index: 10,
  bla: 'x'
});
```

always compiles to:

```
console.info({b:"bar",index:10,a:"x"});
```

property "index" will never be renamed to some different name. The question is why? And how to force it's rename?

Comment: This is a pretty tricky one. This issue comment by one of the closure compiler devs may provide some insight: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/1054#issuecomment-127026064.

Comment: Yes, this is cool, but there is no "index" member on Object.prototype at all...

Comment: @Ruslan FYI this is intended behavior.  The compiler checks for known property names and avoids renaming them

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the Closure Compiler can rename based on types.  However, it does back off in the face of loose types.  Object literals that are not directly assigned to prototype properties are one of those loose types.  Here it is not renamed because an "index" property exists in the standard externs.  There are several definition but here is one:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/641cf61b99280b8bb4b62ecce873e51208501fec/externs/es3.js#L718

Comment: Still I can't understand why it's not collapsed on Object.prototype, is it so hard for GCC to determine that this property is coming from the instance that is not related with the Array?

Comment: It just doesn't try very hard with object literals.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't have a time for understanding this "very smart logic", I'll just rename this property to something else that is not used by other objects.